# Cannot Access Remote Network IP & Host from Openvpn server

Tags: vpn, openvpn, routing

I have installed OpenVPN server on Ubuntu 14 in my LAN and I have configured OpenVPN client on DD-WRT router at remote site, same client connected to OpenVPN server and can able to access server side host successfully (ERP or Mail).

Now I'm not able to ping from server LAN network or OpenVPN server to remote host.

My server config

```
port 4096
proto udp
mode server
tls-server
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
auth SHA512
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 172.30.30.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
route 174.30.30.0 255.255.255.0 172.30.30.3
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
#push "redirect-gateway def1"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
#crl-verify crl.pem
```

Client config

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xx.xx.xxx.xx 4096
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
key-direction 1
verb 3
```

Current Routing & Firewall on Server

```
netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table

Destination Gateway Genmask Flags MSS Window irtt Iface
0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 ens33
172.20.20.0 172.30.30.3 255.255.255.0 UG 0 0 0 tun0
172.30.30.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 tun0
192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 ens33
```

Current Routing & Firewall INFO on Client DD WRT

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table

Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0 192.168.20.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth0
127.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 U 0 0 0 lo
169.254.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 0 0 0 br0
172.20.20.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 br0
172.30.30.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 tun1
192.168.0.0 172.30.30.1 255.255.255.0 UG 0 0 0 tun1
192.168.20.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 eth0
```

I tried to enable NAT & disable NAT at DD-WRT, still the server side cannot access any remote host even from VPN server.

Appreciate for your time and if any solution available, if I can access remote LAN host from OpenVPN server end.

Anybody can help, everything is working except, the server side, cannot ping to OpenVPN client configured on DD-WRT route & its LAN host?
Top

-Thanks,
 Sam

Answer (score 0):

You have configured server.conf and created a self signed certificate, but after that you have missed a step. After creating self signed certificates, edit the server.conf file again and give a path to the certificates in the server folder:

```
ca /file_path/ca.crt        
cert /file_path/server.crt     
key /file_path/server.key         
dh /file_path/dh2048.pem
```